# Vector fields on the $5$-sphere

Tags: differential-topology, vector-fields

What is the maximum number of smooth, linearly-independent vector fields that can exist on the $5$-sphere?

Comment: How much do you know about Stiefel-Whitney class and $K$-theory?

Comment: I assume you mean "linearly independent at each point $p \in S^5$, not "linearly independent in the vector space of all such fields". Is that right?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Point taken.  I was only trying to gauge whether a simple reference to John Adam's paper would suffice as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) There certainly exists at least $1$ smooth linearly independent vector field on $S^5$ (i.e. nonzero at each $x\in S^5$), namely $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)\mapsto (x_2,-x_1,x_4,-x_3,x_6,-x_5)$ . 
2) There do not even exist $2$ linearly independent *continuous* vector fields on $S^5$.
This is proved  in Steenrod's [The Topology of Fibre Bundles](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/1973.html), published in 1951 (before $K$-theory was invented): Theorem 27.11, page 142.
No Chern classes are  used either.
The only tool used is (rather advanced) homotopy theory, which is developed in Part II of the book.

**Another reference**
As mentioned by @user10354138, Adams has reproved  the result above, and much more !, using K-theory (a freshly invented technique in 1961) in his article [Vector Fields on Spheres](https://apurvnakade.github.io/notes/CMI/vector%20fields%20on%20spheres/adams2.pdf)

Comment: Got it. Thanks Georges Elencwajg....That sure is something else. Beautiful..... S^1, S^3 and S^7 sure are unique.